# How to show ad after user clicks on listview item but not for every item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, admob

I have a listview populated with data from a remote database. When the user clicks on an item they are taken to a detail screen. My question is how do I show and ad when the user clicks on a list item but not everytime they click on a list item. I don't want to show an ad with every list item click just like after every 5 clicks or so. How would I go about doing that? I'm assuming some sort of logic within the listview onItemClickListener. I just have no idea what that logic would look like.

**EDIT**

Per user8's answer, I've added a counter and shared prefs to the onItemClickListener. Nothing happens when I click on an item though. Not even to see the DetailActivity. Here's my code:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Get item at position
                RowData item = (RowData)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);


                int clickCount = prefs.getInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, 1);
                if (clickCount % 5 == 0) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                clickCount++;
                prefs.edit().putInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, clickCount).apply();

                //Start details activity
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok. I see what was going wrong. Per user8's answer, when the user clicks 5 times it shows an ad yet if the user clicks less than 5 times nothing happens. So I added an else statement so now the user can click a list item and go to the detail activity. An ad will still show after every 5 clicks but won't be "stale" in between ads. Here's the working code:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Get item at position
                RowData item = (RowData)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);


                int clickCount = prefs.getInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, 1);
                if (clickCount % 5 == 0) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }else{
                startActivity(intent);
                }
                clickCount++;
                prefs.edit().putInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, clickCount).apply();

                //Start details activity
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have any objections to using a static counter variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in your `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

int clickCount = prefs.getInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, 0);
if (clickCount > 0 && clickCount % 5 == 0) {
    showAd();
}
clickCount++;
prefs.edit().putInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, clickCount).apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do that, it just depends on what is easiest for you.

1) As Daniel K mentioned in his comment, a counter variable, kept in the class itself, can just be incremented every time a click is registered

2) You can keep a slightly more persistent variable by using [shared preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) (which will persist after the app is closed)

3) If you have a MyApplication class, you can use static variables there too which will serve the same function as option 1.

4) You could use a database (though that is likely too much work for that to be honest).

I personally would recommend shared preferences because it will keep track of the clicks even after a user closes and re-opens the app, that way, if a user clicks 4 times, closes the app, and comes back another day to click 4 more times (again and again), you will still get a result every 5 clicks as opposed to waiting for them to click 5 times in a single session.

-PGMac

Comment: I did not consider persistence, great advice.

Comment: Interesting. Nice point. I'm gonna try the Shared Prefs method and see how that pans out. I do have an Application class that I  could use if need be.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck to ya! If you really want to be mysterious, you could always keep a separate persisted int of how many clicks before a popup ad comes and change it dynamically (like every 5, then 10, then 5) etc. Just in case you don't want users to see a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following changes. I wanted to show it after every 3 clicks.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int position = getAdapterPosition();


    final  Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),VideoPlayActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("data",childlistData.get(position).getData());


    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    int clickCount = prefs.getInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, 1);
    if (clickCount % 3 == 0) {


        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);


        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                interstitial.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad failed to load! error code: " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad left application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad is opened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(" divisible by 3 "+clickCount);

    }else{
        System.out.println("not divisible by 3 "+clickCount);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    clickCount++;

    System.out.println("Counter Value"+clickCount);
    prefs.edit().putInt(KEY_CLICK_COUNT, clickCount).apply();
}
```